# Why does installing any version of ubuntu 16.4.3 fail?

Tags: radeon, login-screen

so my problem is as goes: When I try to install Ubuntu 16.4.4 from a flashdrive it goes to a black screen says something about “tsc deadline disabled due to errata” and something about upgrading microcontroller. Than a nice Ubuntu splashscreen with moving dots appears and than I see the error once again only this time in my native resolution. Than black screen. After that a normal login flashes, I even hear the login sound. Than poof black screen and again and againg in a loop. Mind you, that all I wanted to do is install the ubuntu nothing more. (From what I have found out, my first suspect would be my Radeon r7 200 GPU altough it works just fine under windows that I have with the old Ubuntu 16.4.3 in dual boot (I encounter similar bug when I do sudo apt update upgrade in 16.4.3)) So yeah, what can I do to even install Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe you want to try the alternate installer: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: @davidbaumann This problem doesn't appear on my HP ProBook 4520s with the same flash drive so I don't think, that this will help.